# TextBlock TextWrapping not wrapping #2

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock, word-wrap

OK... so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625177/textblock-textwrapping-not-wrapping) solution doesn't help

XAML is here

```
  <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContentItems}" Background="White" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,0,5">Start</Label><svl:TimeEditor Value="{Binding Path=FormatedStart}" Width="87"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="2,8"  Name="dtpStart" FontSize="12"  Height="25"  VerticalAlignment="Center"     />
                                    <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,0,5">End</Label><svl:TimeEditor Value="{Binding Path=FormatedEnd}" Width="87"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="2,8"  Name="dtpEnd" FontSize="12"  Height="25"  VerticalAlignment="Center"     />
                                </StackPanel>                               
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  Name="tbText" Text="{Binding Path=Data}"></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well your `TextBlock` does not need to wrap since your specifying `Width` as `Auto` for it's `ColumnDefinition` which allows it to take all the `Width` it needs to fit Content even at the cost of overflowing. You either need to set the Column's Width to "*" to allow the `TextWrapping` to kick in when requested width exceeds allowable or manually force a `MaxWidth` on it using a Binding like

```
<TextBlock Name="tbText" Grid.Row="1" MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=ActualWidth}" Text="{Binding Path=Data}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Answer (score 13):

```
The following will helps for text wrapping:

<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```