# Why TextWrapping for the TextBlock in the Grid works only if I specify TexBlock Width?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Why TextWrapping for the TextBlock in the Grid works only if I specify TexBlock Width?

When I remove TextBlock MaxWidth Property TextWrapping is not working.

Full code for ComboBox

```
<Window Height="600" Width="480">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedIndex="0" x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Code}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="50"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Name="Column1"  MaxWidth="300"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Code}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=Column1, Path=MaxWidth}" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible sample of your issue. What is the parent element of the Grid for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextBlock TextWrapping not wrapping #2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221073/textblock-textwrapping-not-wrapping-2)

Comment: I added full code for combobox.

Comment: You should include all parent elements of the ComboBox as well, all the way up to the parent window. Please provide a minimal sample that anyone can run as-is.

Comment: Updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why TextWrapping for the TextBlock in the Grid works only if I specify TexBlock Width?

Because the Grid gets added to an invisible ScrollViewer when the ComboBox is opened. You could fix this and get the text to wrap by simply setting the ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility attached property of the ComboBox to Disabled:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
              SelectedIndex="0" x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Code}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Width="100" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="50"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="300"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Code..."/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                           Text="some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text" 
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ComboBox>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason is by defining your ColumnDefinition as `Auto` or `*` or `not setting it at all` you have nothing to limit the size available for your TextBlock to consume. So it would be expected behavior for the Text to not Wrap. So you'll have to define a Width or MaxWidth on either the ColumnDefinition or the TextBlock directly in order for wrapping to work.

Comment: I defined MaxWidth for ColumnDefinition, but TextWrapp is not working. It only works if I define MaxWidth for the TextBlock. Why?

Comment: Not specifying the width for column will result in textbox data overflowing the column. Instead you can try giving either a fixed width for both column and textbox. Actually textbox maxwidth need to be mandatorily specified for wrapping to work. Else its width will be automatically  increased while text is entered.