# Screen does not display full content of string

Tags: xaml

i'm using the textblock to display the content,but for the long content, it just cut off and not display the content fully while i'm sure that the i filled the content string. Pls show me where my code is wrong. Thanks

Link of the my screen: www.flickr.com/photos/37903269@N05/15332152972/

my xaml code :

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <!-- <phone:WebBrowser VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="webBrowser1" /> -->
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_DetailPage">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>                            

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                       />

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, i fixed it.Because of the limitation of sing UI: 4096px limit of size. So there is a need to split the long content in the more than one TextBlock or you can create a scrollabe textbock as [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3af9bc99-2526-49fc-b4a5-4170e12d11ab/do-textblocks-have-a-max-line-limit-if-so-how-do-i-increase-it?forum=wpdevelop)

Answer (score 0):

I executed the code shared and it seems to wrap text as shown in the screen shot below.

[image]

The screenshot you shared seems to have vertical cropping of the text as well. For that, we can set the ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility to 'Auto' with proper Height given.

Also, for your additional knowledge or may be future use, here are some stackoverflow questions which explains the text 'NOT WRAPPING' issue for StackPanel

[TextBlock TextWrapping not wrapping inside StackPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430705/textblock-textwrapping-not-wrapping-inside-stackpanel)

[TextBlock TextWrapping not wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625177/textblock-textwrapping-not-wrapping)