# How to wrap controls in StackPanel?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

My problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625177/textblock-textwrapping-not-wrapping)
but the solutions require the use of `DockPanel` which is not available in UWP.

I have a `CheckBox` on the left and a `StackPanel` on the right. This `StackPanel` has two `TextBlock`s and a `Hyperlink`. I want to wrap the text in this `StackPanel`. I have also tried replacing this `StackPanel` with `Grid` but I can't figure it out. Here's the XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="22"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<CheckBox Grid.Column="0"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                Grid.Column="1">

        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind TermsViewModel.Terms1}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <HyperlinkButton Content="{x:Bind Link}"
                         NavigateUri="someRandomUri"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind TermsViewModel.Terms2}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Should the two `TextBlock` and `HyperlinkButton` have the same width or different width?

Comment: @VijayNirmal can be diferent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Hyperlink in middle of a paragraph you don't want to use `StackPanel`.You just need `TextBlock`. Here is the code sample

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Run Text=""/>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="someRandomUri">
        <Run Text=""/>
    </Hyperlink>
    <Run Text=""/>
</TextBlock>
```

To learn more about [Create a Hyperlink text element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/hyperlinks#create-a-hyperlink-text-element)

Comment: Nope. Dividing into 3 different columns, the text of last column will wrap inside the third column only. The text should start from the first column ( on new line ).

Comment: I can't understand. Can you explain little more clearly?

Comment: When the text of last column gets wrapped, it stays in the last column only. So the first line is full of text (starting from first column ) but in the second line, the text is starting from the third column. I want it to start from the first column in the second line also ( so that it looks like all the text is in a single TextBlock )